# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called - using tag to identify TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've seen a number of people who have asked a similar thing, but answers to their questions are not the answers to mine.

1) I have created a single view application with an empty View Controller.  In that, I dragged a new Table View (style Plain) with a single prototype cell of style Basic.

2) I am trying to learn about dynamically changing the behaviour of TableViews, so I have a mutable array called sectionRows, which will contain the number of rows per section.  At the moment, a single section with a number of rows would be an achievement :)

3) In my ViewController.h I have set the delegates

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

I have also control-dragged from the TableView to the ViewController Yellow-Circle and set the datasource and delegate outlets.

4) In my ViewController.m, I have defined some global variables

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionRows;
    UITableView *myTableView;
}
```

The first is my data array (containing the number of rows per section and the second is a pointer to my TableView, which I have identified using a numeric View tag of '1'.

5) In my viewDidLoad, I initialize everything:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myTableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    sectionRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create sectionarray

    [sectionRows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];

    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

As you can see, I even make sure that I set the datasource and delegate again but this hasn't made any difference.

5) I have overloaded 3 methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Returning %@ rows", [sectionRows objectAtIndex:section]);
    return (NSInteger)[sectionRows objectAtIndex:section]; // the number referenced in the array...
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Returning %li sections", sectionRows.count);
    return sectionRows.count; // the size of the sectionRows array
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"xxx";
    NSLog(@"Setting cell to %@", cell);
    return cell;
}
```

Now, when I run this, I am getting NSLog returning confirmation that there is a single section and a single row:

```
2014-07-27 19:58:34.599 TableViewTests[12877:60b] Returning 1 sections
2014-07-27 19:58:34.600 TableViewTests[12877:60b] Returning 1 rows
```

However, as you can see cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called.

None of the other things I have seen point to what I am doing wrong.  I am doing what I thought I did successfully in another simple project (to learn) but I must be doing something else differently.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Upload your project somewhere and put a link to it in your question, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: You don't need to use the tags. Just control-drag the tableView into your interface and you can reference it there.

Comment: Thanks Doctorcoder.  Using tags was advice I received from elsewhere, which seems to make sense if I want to be specific about what it is I am referring to.

If I control-drag the tableView into the interface.  How do I reference it. i.e. what is its name?  If I provide a Tag, then I can give it a name which is completely unambiguous. If I have 2 TableViews on a single page (ugly but possible), then what would each of these be called in your scenario?

Are you suggesting I use IBOutlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Returning %@ rows", [sectionRows objectAtIndex:section]);
    return (NSInteger)[sectionRows objectAtIndex:section]; // the number referenced in the array...
}
```

This is incorrect. You cannot cast what you get from your array to an `NSInteger`. It's a pointer. Assuming you store `NSNumber`s into the array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Returning %@ rows", [sectionRows objectAtIndex:section]);
    return [[sectionRows objectAtIndex:section] integerValue]; // the number referenced in the array...
}
```

Comment: Thanks duciy9y = that sorted it.  I have to wait 5 minutes to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: @JonM If you're new to iOS, I suggest building up a basic background in C first. You don't seem to know what pointers are.

Comment: Thanks @duci9y - I actually have a long history of C (25+ years). That pointer error was so obvious when you highlighted it but the syntax for Objective-C is what is confusing me.  I am doing some very simple projects to get me in the swing of using Obj-C approaches, including some very basic array handling etc. It is not as intuitive as I would have hoped.

Comment: @JonM Good luck! If you're looking for resources, I suggest Stanford's CS193P as a starting point.